# Backward slash in String JavaScript doesn't count in length, why so?

Tags: javascript, string

Backward slash in String JavaScript doesn't count in length, and disapears together with number when it is ptinted. I tried to google it, not quite sure what to call it. What is going on in this code?

```
var b = "world\0";
alert(b.length)                        // 6
console.log( "world\0" );       // world  (we see here only 5 characters!)
```

Why so?

Comment: because ``\`` is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)

Comment: The question is unclear. And the null character isn't supposed to disappear, how comes you see nothing ? It normally appears as a rectangle: https://i.imgur.com/od4wdED.png

Comment: Your title and question don't match up.

Comment: Guys, we don't need so many identical answers.

Comment: Sorry for inconveniance, I couldn't put it all together in a question because there are lot details to take in consideration before asking and i didn't know what to call it. That's why I used what I knew for that moment: "string and back slash behaves very strange" would sound even worse for my opinion

Answer (score 4):

`\0` is an *escape sequence* that creates a single character (just like `\t` creates a single character [a tab], `\n` creates a single newline, etc.) The character's character code is 0 (vs. 9 for tab or 10 for newline). So the string really has six characters in it:

`w` ([U+0077](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0077))

`o` ([U+006F](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=006F))

`r` ([U+0072](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0072))

`l` ([U+006C](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=006C))

`d` ([U+0064](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0064))

`\0` ([U+0000](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0000))

On most consoles, you'll see character 0 as a little box or a diamond with a question mark in it, but some may not show it at all (Node.js's console for instance, at least as of this writing).

I should note that `\0` producing U+0000 is a special case. `\1` does *not* produce U+0001, etc. Perhaps straying somewhat from the topic, but if you want to specify a character by its character code, you have three choices:

- If the character fits in a single UTF16 code unit whose value fits in two hex digits, you can use a hex escape sequence: `\xXX` where `XX` is exactly two hex digits.
- If the character fits in a single UTF16 code unit (regardless of whether that value fits in two digits), you can also use a Unicode code unit escape sequence: `\uXXXX` where `XXXX` is exactly four hex digits.
- If the character requires two UTF16 code units (a "surrogate pair"), you can either use two Unicode code unit escapes, or the newer (ES2015+) Unicode code *point* escape sequence: `\u{X+}` where `X+` is one or more hex digits whose value is `<= 0x10FFFF` (the maximum code point in Unicode at present).

(If you're unfamiliar with the terms "code unit" and "code point," I've written up [this blog post](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/01/26/what-is-a-string/) about it and about JavaScript strings in general.)

For example, we can write the English capital letter `A` as `\x41`, `\u0041`, or `\u{41}` because it needs just a single UTF16 code unit and that code unit's value fits in two hex digits. We can write the latin capital A-with-macron (Ā) as `\u0100` or `\u{100}` because it, too, requires only a single code unit — but we can't use a hex escape sequence (`\xXX`) because the code unit's value doesn't fit in two hex digits. The emoji  requires two code units; we can write it either by writing out those two code units (`\uD83D\uDE09`) or by writing a single code point (`\u{1F609}`) (we can't use `\xXX` to write it, because each of its code units is too large for two hex digits; that's true of all UTF16 code units that are part of a surrogate pair, because of the way UTF16 is defined).

Live Examples:

```js
// The letter A
const a1 = "A";
const a2 = "\x41";
const a3 = "\u0041";
const a4 = "\u{41}";
console.log(a1, a2, a3, a1 === a2, a2 === a3, a3 === a4);

// The letter Ā (A-with-macron)
const m1 = "Ā";
const m2 = "\u0100";
const m3 = "\u{100}";
console.log(m1, m2, m3, m1 === m2, m2 === m3);

// The emoji 
const e1 = "";
const e2 = "\uD83D\uDE09";
const e3 = "\u{1F609}";
console.log(e1, e2, e3, e1 === e2, e2 === e3);
```

Comment: Indeed, I checked on Node.js console... Thank you for clarification!

Comment: This is a great explanation - seeing `\u0000` and how it's counted as  a single character makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Here `\` is an escape character so it is not counted as a length in the string.

So `"world\0"` has 6 charactes. i.e. `w, o, r, l, d, \0`

But you do not see `\0` here is because that is a [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) but it is there somewhere.

Comment: Thank you! So, \0 - is "escape sequence" of null character.

Answer (score 0):

**Special Characters In Javascript**

Because strings must be written within quotes, JavaScript will misunderstand this string:

```
var x = "We are the so-called "Vikings" from the north.";
```

The string will be chopped to "We are the so-called ".

The solution to avoid this problem is to use the **backslash escape character**.

The backslash (\) escape character turns special characters into string characters:

- `\'` -> output `'`
- `\"` -> output `"`
- `\\` -> output `\`

sample:

```
var x = "We are the so-called \"Vikings\" from the north.";
```

That's why the single backslash character will not count.

Source:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp