# Length of string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following string returns a length of 20 in Javascript, but why?

`8080!\u001b[22m\u001b[32m\u001b[39m`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backward slash in String JavaScript doesn't count in length, why so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48741428/backward-slash-in-string-javascript-doesnt-count-in-length-why-so)

Comment: @snipsnipsnip This post is about Unicode characters and the post you are referencing is about the backslash character specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\u001b` is the Unicode value for `Escape` which is counted as a single character. With that in mind, the length is 20.

Answer (score 2):

When JavaScript interprets that string expression, the actual value is: [image: Image of string evaluated by JavaScript] (length 20).

See it below:

```js
console.log('8080!\u001b[22m\u001b[32m\u001b[39m');

console.log('length:', '8080!\u001b[22m\u001b[32m\u001b[39m'.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your strings contains unicode escaped characters, this is the string character by character (using `split`):

```js
var str = '8080!\u001b[22m\u001b[32m\u001b[39m';

console.log(str.split(''));
```